# Angular2 Grab all Canvas Elements in View Template from Component?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

I'd like to grab all the canvas elements from a component's view template.  The canvas elements are rendered in a ngFor, so I could have 0,... canvas elements in the viewtemplate.  I need to grab them and use a component method to draw them.  How can i write a selector to grab all the canvas elements that are in the DOM nested in the view template?